# Is $I-\partial_x^2:H_0^1 \to (H_0^1)^* $ isomorphic?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $H_0^1(\Omega)$ be the usual Sobolev sapce, where $\Omega=[0,1]$ and $H_0^1(\Omega)^*$ be its dual space. Define
$$I-\partial_x^2:u\in H_0^1(\Omega)\to (u-u_{xx},\cdot)_{H^1_0(\Omega)}\in (H_0^1(\Omega))^*.$$
Is the above operator isomorphic from $H_0^1(\Omega)$ to its dual?